# How to add recursive option to mocha programatically?

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js

I followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically) to run mocha programmatically. However I can't figure out how to add `--recursive` option which I could add, when I test using `npm test`.

```
var Mocha = require('mocha'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

// Instantiate a Mocha instance.
var mocha = new Mocha();

var testDir = 'some/dir/test'

// Add each .js file to the mocha instance
fs.readdirSync(testDir).filter(function(file){
    // Only keep the .js files
    return file.substr(-3) === '.js';

}).forEach(function(file){
    mocha.addFile(
        path.join(testDir, file)
    );
});

// Run the tests.
mocha.run(function(failures){
  process.on('exit', function () {
    process.exit(failures);  // exit with non-zero status if there were failures
  });
});
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve. When you run `npm test` should that invoke your node script, which then _always_ recursively obtains the test `.js` files from the directory; E.g. `some/dir/test`, and runs each test?

Comment: @RobC I'm aware of that option. However I'm doing some dynamic code analysis and I need to run tests programmatically (not with `npm test`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [--recursive](https://mochajs.org/#usage) option for [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) is a command-line option. It can only be applied when invoking Mocha via the command-line, i.e. when utilizing the following usage syntax:

> `Usage: mocha [debug] [options] [files]`

Your current implementation of [`fs.readdirSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) in your node script does not obtain the `.js` test files recursively. It's obtaining the paths at the the top-level of your directory only.

`fs.readdirSync()` does not provide an option to read a directory recursively.

Consider writing a custom function which recursively obtains the `.js` test files.

For example:

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    Mocha = require('mocha');

// Instantiate a Mocha instance.
var mocha = new Mocha();

var testDir = 'path/to/test/files/';

/**
 * Gets the test .js file paths recursively from a given directory.
 * @param {String} dir - path to directory containing test files.
 * @returns {Array} Filepaths to each test .js file.
 */
function getTestPaths(dir, fileList) {
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    fileList = fileList || [];

    files.forEach(function(file) {
        if (fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory()) {
            fileList = getTestPaths(path.join(dir, file), fileList);
        } else {
            fileList.push(path.join(dir, file));
        }
    });

    return fileList.filter(function (file) {
        return path.extname(file) === '.js';
    });
}

// Get all .js paths and add each file to the mocha instance.
getTestPaths(testDir).forEach(function(file) {
    mocha.addFile(
        path.join(file)
    );
});

// Run the tests.
mocha.run(function(failures) {
    process.on('exit', function () {
        process.exit(failures);
    });
});
```

**Note:** The `getTestPaths` function recursively walks the directory and returns an Array of `.js` filepaths.